# Deploy Vue.js app to Apache server

Tags: file-structure

i need some help. I wrote an SPA using VueJs. I ran "npm run build" so i can test my app on my Xampp server. The build generated a "/dist" folder. I changed the index.html in the dist folder to index.php. I tried serving the dist folder with Xampp but it shows a blank page. Please help. I have uploaded the image showing the errors

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae7GM.jpg

Comment: Are there errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Yes there are, it shows GET requests to the js files but they all failed. A 404 error code

Comment: That sounds like something you should fix, then. Figure out why those URLs aren't returning the files you expect.

Comment: If i figured it out, i wouldn't post this question. Please help

Comment: We can't help, because you haven't really provided any information. It's probably something simple like URLs that say `/dist/foo.js` but you've got them at `/foo.js` with your server config.

Comment: @ceejayoz i've included an image showing the errors.

Comment: Go into the network panel, refresh, and see where your browser is trying to find those files. Then, take a look at your `dist` folder structure and figure out where the mis-match is. Your screenshot doesn't tell me much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; a bunch of 404's in my console after running 
`npm run build`. Ceejayoz is correct in suggesting you take a look at your network tab to see where the server is expecting to reach the file.

His suggestion tipped me off that my application did not have a base URL set. 
[Vue's docs on this](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js).

After setting the path my app was located at, I reran the build process and it came right up.

Answer (score 0):

dist files can only be served via http, you have to deploy it to your hosting server before you can see the output of your vue app